# Job never complete when calling Job.join()

Tags: kotlin, viewmodel, kotlin-flow

can someone tel me why this Job.join() never complete ?

```
private fun handleNotification() {
        val job = Job()
        val scope = viewModelScope + job

        scope.launch {
            getUserInfoUseCase().collectLatest { result ->
                _state.value = when (result) {
                    is ResultWrapper.Success -> _state.value.copy(user = result.value)
                    is ResultWrapper.Error -> ...
                    ResultWrapper.NetworkError -> ...
                }
            }
        }
        viewModelScope.launch {
            job.children.forEach { it.join() }
            Timber.d("NOTIFICATION :: User = ${state.value.user}")
            Timber.d("NOTIFICATION :: Notification = $notification")
        }
    }
```

I will want to add some extra job after. May is cause the getUserInfoUseCase() steel collecting ?

Answer (score 1):

If `getUserInfoUseCase()` is like most real-world-application Flows, it is an infinite flow. That means that if you call `collect` on it, `collect` suspends forever. Therefore, calling `join` on a Job that is waiting for such a `collect` call will also suspend forever.

For example, a Flow returned by Room monitors the database for changes forever. It's always possible some future change could be coming that will result in another emission, so the Flow has no end.

If you just want to wait for the flow's first emission, maybe you could use a channel like this.

```
private fun handleNotification() {
        val firstFlowItemChannel = Channel<Unit>(1)

        scope.launch {
            getUserInfoUseCase().collectLatest { result ->
                _state.value = when (result) {
                    is ResultWrapper.Success -> _state.value.copy(user = result.value)
                    is ResultWrapper.Error -> ...
                    ResultWrapper.NetworkError -> ...
                }
                firstFlowItemChannel.send(Unit)
            }
        }
        viewModelScope.launch {
            firstFlowItemChannel.receive()
            Timber.d("NOTIFICATION :: User = ${state.value.user}")
            Timber.d("NOTIFICATION :: Notification = $notification")
        }
    }
```

Comment: i think man is no need for channel, we need just to join the job thats returned from the first lunch

Comment: @Mohmmaed-Amleh That’s what OP already tried and said didn’t work. I’m guessing it’s because `collectLatest` never returns due to an infinite flow as explained in the first paragraph of my answer.